# Sound from mic vs sound from speaker

Tags: c++, api, windows-xp, waveform

I want to capture audio from both the mic and the speaker - separately. How can I distinguish between them? I can capture one or the other using the Wave API, e.g., WaveInOpen().

When I enumerate the devices using waveInGetNumDevs() and waveInGetDevCaps()/waveoutGetDevCaps(), there seems to be no information related to a particular end-point device (e.g., mic or speaker). I only see the following, which are adapter devices:

HD Read Audio Input
HD Read Audio Output
Webcam ...

Comment: Wouldn't you expect that an audio *input* device is a microphone and an *output* device is a speaker?

Comment: nah, he probably meant mixer as speaker

Comment: I mean, the audio outputted by media players. Using EXACTLY the same app, I can capture the mic input and the audio emitted by media players. The problem is that none of the functions that I use seems to indicate the source of the audio. Of course, I know whether it's the mic or the media player, but not my app.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually no knowledge of the windows API so my answer isn't probably the best and there maybe even better ways.

```
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnum = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pEnum);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      IMMDeviceCollection *pDevices;
      // Enumerate the output devices.
      hr = pEnum->EnumAudioEndpoints(eAll, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, &pDevices);
      // You can choose between eAll, eCapture or eRender
    }
```

With that you'd be able to distinguish between input (capture) and output (render).
(That's what you wanted right?)

The code is taken from [this article](http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/). You may look at it for the correct API calls and libraries, it even might give you some more information.

Hope that's helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I forgot to mention that the code is for XP - my bad.